# How can I stop RNN after generating a special output word in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to implement an encoder-decoder model for sequence to sequence learning.

Encoder reads the input sequence word by word and update its hidden state.

Decoder uses the hidden state of encoder to initializing its hidden state. and then generating output with respect to last generated output (y(t-1)) and its hidden state. I want to stop this procedure when a special output () is generated. In fact, I want to able to generate different length outputs. How can I do that in Tensorflow?

Comment: There is a tutorial on sequence-to-sequence models in TensorFlow, take a look. [https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html)

Comment: I read that code. However, it does not stop when a special output is generated. In fact, it divides instances into buckets, and generate output based on each bucket's output size. In other words, it does not an approach for stop generating output if it generated a special output.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want something like the `sequence_length` of `tf.nn.rnn`. I want it too, but it seems TensorFlow doesn't have it.

What I've being doing so far and found a good way around this limitation is to pad the decoder labels at train time with the EOS symbol. Usually, you would need only one of these, but filling a lot of them doesn't do any harm.

At execution time, you either control each iteration manually to stop when the first EOS is produced or just run a predefined number of time steps and then remove the extra EOS symbols from your output. The decoder quickly learns that after the first EOS, only more EOS may follow.